# How to get the scale percentage of an image when using background-size:cover?

Tags: css, background

I need to figure out how much an image has scaled.

I am setting a background image to the `body` with the `background-size: cover`.

Basically, no matter what size the screen is, the image will always keep its aspect ratio and expand (or shrink) until it fills both the width and height of the screen. It will then position itself so it centers both vertically and horizontally with the “excess” cropped.

Assuming that I know

1. The original background image size
2. The screen/viewport site

how can I figure out how much the image has actually scaled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we suppose your image has a dimension of `WxH` and the screen size is `AxB` then it should be the biggest value between `A/W` and `B/H`.

Some examples:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0) center/cover;
}
/*
we will have 1.333 = 400/300 and 0.6667 = 200/300
*/
img {
 transform:scale(1.3333);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0">
```

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=0) center/cover;
}
/*
we will have 0.6 = 300/500 and 0.4 = 200/500
*/
img {
 transform:scale(0.6);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=0">
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:300px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=0) center/cover;
  display:inline-block;
}
/*
we will have 0.25 = 100/400 and 1 = 300/300
*/
img {
 transform:scale(1);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=0">
```

With `contain` we take the smallest value:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0) left/contain no-repeat;
}
/*
we will have 1.333 = 400/300 and 0.6667 = 200/300
*/
img {
 transform:scale(0.6667);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0">
```

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=0) left/contain no-repeat;
}
/*
we will have 0.6 = 300/500 and 0.4 = 200/500
*/
img {
 transform:scale(0.4);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=0">
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:300px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=0) top/contain no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
/*
we will have 0.25 = 100/400 and 1 = 300/300
*/
img {
 transform:scale(0.25);
 transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=0">
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Essentially, the calculation is `screenW / imageW` and `screenH / imageH`. Which ever value is the highest is the scale amount.